# Empty page when put TabLayoutPanel to SplitLayoutPanel

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT code, but the result is empty page. why?

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    leftPanelSetup();

    rightPanelSetup();

    splitPanelSetup();
}



private void splitPanelSetup() {
    SplitLayoutPanel layoutPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel();
    layoutPanel.addWest(leftTabLayoutPanel, 300);
    layoutPanel.addEast(rightTabLayoutPanel, 400);

    RootPanel.get("content").add(layoutPanel);
}

private void leftPanelSetup() {
    // Create a tab panel
    leftTabLayoutPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(1.5, Style.Unit.EM);

    //leftTabPanel.setWidth("300px");

    // 1
    VerticalPanel vPanel1 = new VerticalPanel();
    leftTabLayoutPanel.add(vPanel1, "Russian");

    // 2
    VerticalPanel vPanel2 = new VerticalPanel();
    leftTabLayoutPanel.add(vPanel2, "English");

    // 3
    VerticalPanel vPanel3 = new VerticalPanel();
    leftTabLayoutPanel.add(vPanel3, "French");

    // Make the first tab selected and the tab's content visible
    leftTabLayoutPanel.selectTab(0);

    //RootPanel.get("content").add(tabPanel);
}

private void rightPanelSetup() {
    // Create a tab panel
    rightTabLayoutPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(1.5, Style.Unit.EM);

    //rightTabPanel.setWidth("400px");

    // 1
    VerticalPanel vPanel1 = new VerticalPanel();
    rightTabLayoutPanel.add(vPanel1, "Russian");

    // 2
    VerticalPanel vPanel2 = new VerticalPanel();
    rightTabLayoutPanel.add(vPanel2, "English");

    // 3
    VerticalPanel vPanel3 = new VerticalPanel();
    rightTabLayoutPanel.add(vPanel3, "French");

    // Make the first tab selected and the tab's content visible
    rightTabLayoutPanel.selectTab(0);

    //RootPanel.get("content").add(tabPanel);
}
```

Comment: mm.. yes. i just use playframework there also. but yes.

Comment: Let's say, the playframework is not going to help providing answers. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layoutPanel.setSize("500px", "400px"); fixs it. because by default div's size = 0

Answer (score 2):

Add the `SplitLayoutpanel` to `RootLayoutPanel`, instead of `RootPanel`

Comment: I'm new to GWT and was not able to get my panels within the SplitLayoutPanel to display.  It was due to using the RootPanel instead of the RootLayoutPanel.  Thank you!!!