# GWT SplitLayoutPanel not displaying

Tags: java, gwt

Being very new to GWT, I'm having trouble getting a SplitLayoutPanel to display in Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m using GWT 2.5.0 and the plugin for Eclipse Juno. To see how it works, I followed the example at http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2324 verbatim except for changing RootLayoutPanel to RootPanel and a few other things as suggested in any of the following links:

[GWT widget not showing when I use a SplitLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337924/gwt-widget-not-showing-when-i-use-a-splitlayoutpanel)

[UiBinder and SplitLayoutPanel not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463706/uibinder-and-splitlayoutpanel-not-displaying)

[Can't get SplitLayoutPanel working - GWT + UIBinder are driving me crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495457/cant-get-splitlayoutpanel-working-gwt-uibinder-are-driving-me-crazy/2495577#2495577)

[Empty page when put TabLayoutPanel to SplitLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230766/empty-page-when-put-tablayoutpanel-to-splitlayoutpanel)

No matter what I try, the SplitLayoutPanel does not display; all I get is a blank page. Any thoughts on what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code. Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix/match like that. https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#LayoutPanels

RootPanel system is older approach and does not fit in with concepts of LayoutPanels.

SplitLayoutPanel should not be used with RootPanel. **PERIOD**.

Comment: Layout Panels can be used with RootPanel, provided you handle all the cases. But it is not suggested to do so.

Comment: A fine distinction exists between can/cannot and should/should not :D

Comment: I found the source of my proble. In addition to using RootPanel instead of RootLayoutPanel, the ui.xml file and the source to create it had a couple mistyped elements, even though the project compiled! Sometimes copy/paste can lead to issues, too. :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.